# Shortest-path negative edge: Bellman ford igraph complex analysis

Tags: python, igraph, shortest-path, bellman-ford

**WEIGHTED SHORTEST PATHS**

- weights in the dataset are the importance of the relationship,
- while shortest paths assume this is a cost
- so, use 1/weights as the weights of the shortest path computations
  weights = np.array(g_GC_u.es["weight"])

we need the number of hops on the shortest (weighted) path so, we need to:

- compute the shortest weighted paths (method get_shortest_paths)
- extract the # of hops
- get_shortest_paths() can be used on a SINGLE source vertices at a time
- so, we need to cycle over all elements of src,
  and compute the number of hops towards all target nodes (function n_hops)

```
def n_hops(s, t, w):
    sps = g_GC_u.get_shortest_paths(s, t, output = 'epath', weights = w)
    return [len(sps[i]) for i in range(0,len(sps))]

n_hops_w = []
for s in src:
    n_hops_w += n_hops(s, trg, weights)
```

How can I apply this algorithm using the igraph library if my graph is weighted with negative arcs.
For src I take 200 random nodes

Comment: Feel free to open a feature request on GitHub and ask for this feature to be exposed.

Comment: FYI the next version of python-igraph will be able to handle negative weights in `get_shortest_paths()`.